# is it possible to console.log in Play Framework view?

Tags: javascript, java, scala, playframework-2.0

I was wondering is it possible to console.log in Play view? I want to find out how data is flowing in certain parts of the code.

```
  faqList: Array[FaqModel],
  priorityFaqs: Map[Integer, List[FaqModel]])



@script={
    EntryPoint.header()
    EntryPoint.accountIndex(indexJsRoutes)
    <script type="text/javascript">console.log(@priorityFaqs)</script>
}
```

I know that it is possible to put console.log in @script, like showed above. But is it possible to use it in template like this?

```
else if(priorityFaqs.get("1") != null) {
                                    for(priorityItem <- priorityFaqs.get("1")) {
                                        **console.log(@priorityFaq)**
                                    }
```

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but then it is an error:  illegal start of expression

Comment: this `console.log` here is JavaScript, so you can write it only at places where you can writie JavaScript and that place is inside a `<script></script>`.

Comment: Okay, I see, so maybe there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Use the console from server side ;)

> @for(priorityItem <- priorityFaqs.get("1")) {
>                                               @{System.out.println("test")}
>                                           }